# How do I break out each term of Portfolio Variance of Portfolio with N assets in Python?

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

I am calculating portfolio variance of N assets using the formula: `np.dot(_weights.T, np.dot(_cov, _weights))`

However, for some reason, for a particular period to the next, the portfolio variance changes by A LOT, and I for the life of me can't figure out why this is the case.  I've summed up the covariance table to see if the overall covariances increases or decreases as a rough check and it doesn't change that much.  The weights should also stay static for the 2 periods, so I'm completely confused.

The only other option is I want to break out each term in the portfolio variance formula and see exactly why my portfolio variance changes so much.  Basically compare each term with the next.

Any way to do that in python?